# Is it possible to execute code in VB.NET by sending a SMS?

Tags: vb.net, sms

I'd like to find a way to create an application where, when I send a text message from my phone to a given number, certain code runs and then sends me a text message back. For example, I might send a text message with an instruction "define 'malamute'", and the code would parse the text, then look up in a dictionary website the definition of malamute, and send the definition back to me in a text message.

I've found plenty of great resources on [how to send a text message](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15299/Send-a-Text-Message-to-a-Cell-Phone-from-a-VB-NET) using VB.NET, but I can't find anything on Google or SO about how to execute code using an SMS. I would need this to work in such a way that I can send an SMS with only mobile signal, not Wi-Fi or 4G internet, and so long as the text sends correctly, the code would execute. Is this at all possible to do using VB.NET?

Comment: There are ways to receive SMS in email, then your program just need to read email.

Comment: Email would certainly be easier, you can recieve SMS using `twilio` and they apparently have a good api. That's one option

Comment: Rather than execute code, just have your program listen for text messages, and have your software parse the messages from a predifined list of possible commands.

Comment: @DavidWilson That would surely require the program to be turned on at all times, though, running on a computer or some such. I'd need a situation where even if all of my computers are turned off, I can send a text message and run code.

Comment: Umm, if a computer is turned off, they wont run code. You'll need your computer to have Wake On Lan enabled and send a WoL signal, wait for it to resume - and have your program run at system startup, and on and on :-)

Comment: In short executing code directly with no user privileges in everyday circumstances isn't possible

Comment: why not make an SQLite database, with boolean types allocated to the commands you want it to do, instead of an sms, have it receive an  email, and if the email contains some sort of command and the program detects it, have it trigger you sql query, once the program finishes it data read and sees the values are different, it can execute that command and set the value in the sqlite db back to 0 so you can do it all over again, me personalty, id open my ports and use TCP client and TCP listener.

Comment: @AndrewE, I like the idea, but the whole purpose of it would be to be able to trigger the app without internet access.

Comment: you could do TCP without internet access, as long as it was on the same network, it would work

Comment: Who are you going to send the SMS message to?  How will they process the SMS message if the computer is turned off?